# Hi I'm beginner in dart ,I can't find the main.dart

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

I installed the dart sdk and I did the plugin of dart in the intellij i choose console application ,but i can't find how to do the command line app , it starts the pubspec.yaml not with the main.dart.
(ubuntu linux)
sorry for that kind of question .
help me please

Comment: Right click on the Dart file you want to run and click "Run <name of file>".

Comment: thanks a lot it works , can u tell me how to change the default file from pubspec.yaml to main.dart

Comment: The default in IntelliJ is to launch the last executed program. Since `pub get` are executed as a program it will be seen as the last executed program. So you should only need to Right click on the program one time and can use the normal shortcut afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Run the main script in command line

```
dart main.dart
```